# when i am trying to import my css style from my Main.Module.css in react but it is not working

Tags: html, css, reactjs, visual-studio-code

when i am tr[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67IiN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbs1W.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1OYv.png)ying to import my css style from my Main.Module.css in react but it is not working

how i can rectify this problem

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
import "./Main.Module.css";
```

and also in html you can try this

```
<div className-{"main_container_page"}>
```